# Match And Replace Object From Array In Javascript

Tags: javascript

I Want To Replace Object With Value From Array In JavaScript

Here is The Array
`replace_map = { "u0627": "A", "u0675": "A", "u0673": "A", "u0630": "Z", "u0622": "AA", "u0628": "B", "u067E": "P", "u062A": "T", "u0637": "T", "u0679": "T", "u062C": "J", "u0633": "S", "u062B": "S", "u0635": "S", "u0686": "CH", "u062D": "H", "u0647": "H", "u0629": "H", "u06DF": "H", "u062E": "KH", "u062F": "D", "u0688": "D", "u0632": "Z", "u0636": "Z", "u0638": "Z", "u068E": "Z", "u0631": "R", "u0691": "R", "u0634": "SH", "u063A": "GH", "u0641": "F", "u06A9": "K", "u0642": "K", "u06AF": "G", "u0644": "L", "u0645": "M", "u0646": "N", "u06BA": "N", "u0648": "O", "u0649": "Y", "u0626": "Y", "u06CC": "Y", "u06D2": "E", "u06C1": "H", "u064A": "E", "u06C2": "AH", "u06BE": "H", "u0639": "A", "u0643": "K", "u0621": "A", "u0624": "O", "u060C": "" };`

This Is My Javascript Code

```
<script>
$(function () {
mkTool('utf16-encode', function (text) {
    var encoded = punycode.ucs2.decode(text);
    ret = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < encoded.length; i++) {
        
        var hex = encoded[i].toString(16);
        ret += "\\u0" + hex + "";
    }
    const
    replacements = { "\u0627": "A", "\u0675": "A", "\u0673": "A", "\u0630": "Z", "\u0622": "AA", "\u0628": "B", "\u067E": "P", "\u062A": "T", "\u0637": "T", "\u0679": "T", "\u062C": "J", "\u0633": "S", "\u062B": "S", "\u0635": "S", "\u0686": "CH", "\u062D": "H", "\u0647": "H", "\u0629": "H", "\u06DF": "H", "\u062E": "KH", "\u062F": "D", "\u0688": "D", "\u0632": "Z", "\u0636": "Z", "\u0638": "Z", "\u068E": "Z", "\u0631": "R", "\u0691": "R", "\u0634": "SH", "\u063A": "GH", "\u0641": "F", "\u06A9": "K", "\u0642": "K", "\u06AF": "G", "\u0644": "L", "\u0645": "M", "\u0646": "N", "\u06BA": "N", "\u0648": "O", "\u0649": "Y", "\u0626": "Y", "\u06CC": "Y", "\u06D2": "E", "\u06C1": "H", "\u064A": "E", "\u06C2": "AH", "\u06BE": "H", "\u0639": "A", "\u0643": "K", "\u0621": "A", "\u0624": "O", "\u060C": "" };
    result = ret.replace(
    new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).join('|'), 'g'),
    v => replacements[v]
    );
    return result;
        });
    });           
  </script>
```

I Want To Replace ret Return Object `"\"u0627\"u0633"` match & Replace From array `replace_map`

How Can I Match & replace ret Return Object From array

Comment: what are the characters, you like to replace?

Comment: @nina-scholz hi i want to replace this `"\"u0627\"u0633"` from replace_map with value u0627 value is A and u0633 value is S

Comment: I Want To Replace Unicode u0627 to Tex From Array

Comment: You can use map.has("key"), Key can be ret = "u0" + hex + "";  If map has , use map.get(ret) , you will get A or S accordingly from the map.

Comment: can you please re-edit my code i less know javascript i know php basic i'm student

Comment: like this `return replace_map.has(ret);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a regular expression with all keys of the object (with the real characters) and replace all occurences by using a function.

```js
const
    replacements = { "\u0627": "A", "\u0675": "A", "\u0673": "A", "\u0630": "Z", "\u0622": "AA", "\u0628": "B", "\u067E": "P", "\u062A": "T", "\u0637": "T", "\u0679": "T", "\u062C": "J", "\u0633": "S", "\u062B": "S", "\u0635": "S", "\u0686": "CH", "\u062D": "H", "\u0647": "H", "\u0629": "H", "\u06DF": "H", "\u062E": "KH", "\u062F": "D", "\u0688": "D", "\u0632": "Z", "\u0636": "Z", "\u0638": "Z", "\u068E": "Z", "\u0631": "R", "\u0691": "R", "\u0634": "SH", "\u063A": "GH", "\u0641": "F", "\u06A9": "K", "\u0642": "K", "\u06AF": "G", "\u0644": "L", "\u0645": "M", "\u0646": "N", "\u06BA": "N", "\u0648": "O", "\u0649": "Y", "\u0626": "Y", "\u06CC": "Y", "\u06D2": "E", "\u06C1": "H", "\u064A": "E", "\u06C2": "AH", "\u06BE": "H", "\u0639": "A", "\u0643": "K", "\u0621": "A", "\u0624": "O", "\u060C": "" },
    string = '\u0627\u0633',
    result = string.replace(
        new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).join('|'), 'g'),
        v => replacements[v]
    );

console.log(string);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This Code Will Be Work Here ` return ret;`?

Comment: yes tried and update my code with your code but not working for me please can you check updated code

Comment: can i share files with you if yes then how?

Comment: no. please try with a raw string first and then use the sorce you have. mabe your first part does not return in the wanted format.

Comment: with long text i got this error with your code long string `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence` error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence